# List и упаковка (boxing)

Tags: c#

Недавно [узнал](http://www.dijksterhuis.org/exploring-boxing/), что следующий код не вызывает упаковку:

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>();
myList.Add(2);
```

Но как такое возможно? Ведь C# generics тем и отличаются от шаблонов C++, что код для обобщённого класса генерируется только один раз, и тут уж мы либо обрабатываем все типы как ссылочные, либо как типы значений.

Comment: вопрос толком не понял, но может поможет статья - [Обобщения](http://www.rsdn.ru/article/dotnet/generics.xml)

Comment: А что конкретно неясно?
Код для обобщенного класса генерируется один раз. Один код не может работать как с ссылочными типами, так и с типами значений. Вывод: единственный способ сделать вышеприведённый код рабочим -- это вызывать упаковку, превращая int из типа значений в ссылочный тип.

Comment: Ох, вы перевернули моё представление о дженериках :). Теперь неплохо бы преобразовать комментарий в ответ и зааксептить его. Но первое, кажется, ваша прерогатива.
Кстати, описанное "размношение" класса имеет силу только для типов значений, или даже для List<MyClass1> и List<MyClass2> буду созданы отдельные экземпляры классов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Код для обобщенного класса генерируется один раз.

Да, когда вы объявили, какого типа вам нужен список

Когда вы пишите, что-то вроди `List<int> list = new List<int>();` создаётся экземпляр "отдельного" класса `List` именно для типов `int`, и все значения занесённые в этот список будут находится в стеке, как и значения любого значимого типа, если же значения будут ссылочными, то естественно они будут находится в куче, именно этим генерики и отличаются от `ArrayList` - они не производят упаковку/распаковку

> Кстати, описанное "размношение" класса
> имеет силу только для типов значений,
> или даже для List<MyClass1> и
> List<MyClass2> буду созданы отдельные
> экземпляры классов?

**Да**, вот тривиальный пример кода доказывающий это:

```
void Main()
{
    Generic<int> g1 = new Generic<int>();
    g1.Add(1);
    g1.Add(2);
    Generic<int> g2 = new Generic<int>();
    g2.Add(1);
    Generic<string> g3 = new Generic<string>();
    g3.Add("awdaw");
    Generic<int>.Count;//3
    Generic<string>.Count;//1
}

public class Generic<T>
{
    private List<T> _list;
    public static int Count;
    public Generic() { _list = new List<T>(); }
    public void Add(T value)
    {
        _list.Add(value);
        Count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Это не совсем верно. Для обобщённых типов IL-код генерируется один и тот же, независимо от конкретных параметров типа. Однако во время выполнения генерируется **один и тот же** машинный код для подстановки с аргументами ссылочного типа и **отдельный** код для подстановки со значимыми типами.

Comment: а как среда выполнения распознаёт статические переменные для генериков с различными типами?